# Why Discontinuous function doesn't comply non derivability..

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I've been Studying Differentiability theorems

**Note:** => means comply

!=> mean doesn't comply

1. Differentiability => Continuity
2. Continuity !=> Differentiability
3. Non Differentiability !=> DisContinuity.
4. **Discontinuity !=> Non Differentiability**

I don't understand the last theorem how Discontinuous fn can be Differentiable.
Can any tell me why is that cause I new to calculus..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: (4) is just the contrapositive of (1), so it does in fact hold.

Comment: For single variable functions, it's not possible, see [this qs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712013/is-it-really-true-that-if-a-function-is-discontinuous-automatically-its-not) for a dup question. For multivariable functions, it seems that it is possible, see [here](https://mathinsight.org/differentiable_function_discontinuous_partial_derivatives#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20for%20a,%3D(0%2C0).).

Comment: @anomaly . Should 4. not be Discontinuity$\Rightarrow$ Non Differentiablity ? The $!$ seems wrong.

Comment: @KurtG.: Yeah, that's what I'm referring to.

Comment: @GarethMa: I'm not sure what domain the OP is working with, but it's possible for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ to have all partial derivatives $\partial f / \partial x_j$ exist on a neighborhood of a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ but $f$ not be differentiable on a neighborhood of $p$; that is, it may not satisfy $f(x) = f(p) + L(x - p) + o(|x - p|)$ as $x\to p$ for some linear map $L$. But if the latter does hold, then $f$ must be continuous near $p$; we have $|f(x) - f(p)| = \|L\| O(|x - p|)$ as $x\to p$. I'm not sure what flavor of differentiability the OP is referring to.

Comment: @anomaly: To be fair, I don't know much about multivariable calculus either, it's just googled results that might help, since most people on Math.SE are pretty bad at googling, I must say. Also, "Differentiability Theorem" seems to be reserved for multivariable multidimensional functions, e.g. [here](https://mathinsight.org/differentiability_multivariable_theorem). Not sure though, maybe OP can reply ;)